# Load child component inside other component based on URL route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to load a child component in another component based on the route.

Right now I simply have two pages, and I want to load the third route (`dashboard`) as a child component in the `admin` page.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/admin', name: 'Admin', component: AdminComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent},
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

I start at the login page as default (which is good enough for now). On that page I hit a login button and that will do a redirect from the `LoginComponent`. Like so:

```
public login() {
    this.router.navigate(['/Admin']);
}
```

I then end up on the `/admin` page. But on that page I want to show data, coming from another component, based on the URL. For example, I want that `/admin` redirects to `/admin/dashboard`, so I can show the `dashboard` component inside the `admin` component.

If I then navigate to something like: `/admin/users`. The `dashboard` component should then be replaced with the `users` component. etc.

But how do I get this to work? My admin component looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'admin',
    template: `<h1>Admin page</h1>

                Load child components in this routerLink: (but how?)
                <router-link>/router-link>`,
})
export class AdminComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
}
```

So I basically want to know two things:

- How can I tell angular 2 that `/admin` should always redirect to `/admin/dashboard`
- How can I load (based on the URL `/admin/dashboard`) first the `AdminComponent` and inside it (through a `router-link`) the `Dashboard` component

Comment: Use yet another Routing Component and `router-link` inside the nested Component.

Comment: @Langley Not sure what you mean? Right now when I navigate to `/admin/dashboard` it's not working. I have a `router-link` in the `AdminComponent`, but the `dashboard` component is not showing inside of it. The `Admin` component won't even load when I go to `/admin/dashboard`.

Comment: instead of adding the `/dashboard` route in `AppComponent`, add it in the `AdminComponent` and have `AdminComponent` include another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. That way `AppComponent` will solve the '/admin' part of the path and `AdminComponent` will resolve the second part of the path `/dashboard`. Also note that `router-link` is not a tag is an attribue used to define a route name to travel to, like: `<a [routeLink]="['Admin']">`

Comment: @Langley Thanks, got it working! Had to add `/...` after my `Admin` URL route and forgot to add the `ROUTE_DIRECTIVES` in the `Admin` component as well. But after that it all worked fine. Could you please put your comments in an answer so I have something to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you add `@RouteConfig` to your `AppComponent` it becomes a `Routing Component`. instead of trying to handle the `'/dashboard'` route in `AppComponent` and redirecting, might be better to turn `AdminComponent` into a `Child Routing Component` which can handle the `'/dashboard'` route.

By adding three dots to `path: '/admin/...'` you'll let the Angular Router know that the `/dashboard` part of `/admin/dashboard` will be handled by the Child Routing Component (`AdminComponent`).